# "Grouping" elements to apply bulk changes? (ex: disable multiple buttons at once)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I come from the world of HTML, Javascript and CSS.  In that world, if I want to disable an entire group of buttons I would just add a class and use JQuery to do the work.

Is there a parallel concept in C# or .NET?  I have an "Initialize" button followed by multiple action buttons.  I want to enable them all only after a successful initialization.  How would I accomplish this?

I found questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337298/disable-multiple-button-controls-on-the-page) that allow me to perform actions on *all* controls of a certain type, but this won't work for me.

Comment: Maybe using the Tag of each control? I'm not sure if its possible....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I could add buttons to a panel and disable the panel.  Not a perfect solution as sometimes the buttons might be spread across the UI, but worth posting for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the answer you linked to in the question, I'd (ab)use the Tag field

```
foreach (Button button in (FindControls<Button>(this)).Where(b=>b.Tag=="myclass"))
    button.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Your response would scare normal developers, but I'll beat that code like a red-headed step-child!

Comment: the tag field is an Object, and its purpose is an extensibility point, so you can drop in what ever makes sense - use a c# class with properties, one of which might be "buttonGroup" if that makes more sense.